# With React JSX, does placing a static value prop in curly braces incur any overhead?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I know we can pass dynamically changing props in a JSX element like so:

```
<label htmlFor={dynamicId}/>
```

And we can pass static values like so:

```
<label htmlFor="staticId"/>
```

But what about the following:

```
<label htmlFor={'staticId'}/>
```

Is there an (albeit minor) performance overhead in the last line (internal React caching mechanism/ new string on every render)? Is the last line of code a bad practice or does it just not matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're exactly equivalent. You can use [Babel's playground](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=NoKABGA8A2CGBGBTaYAWAXAttAYgewCcBeAIgGd1Z0BLAYwEkATEgegD4AacKOJFDbPmIBvAOQUqdJqIC-7EAF0gA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2017%2Clatest%2Creact&prettier=true&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=) to try it out:

```
[
  <label htmlFor="staticId"/>,
  <label htmlFor={'staticId'}/>
]
```

transpiles to

```
[
  React.createElement("label", { htmlFor: "staticId" }),
  React.createElement("label", { htmlFor: "staticId" })
];
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, good to know the compiler does this. So I guess it comes down to convention/ readability (e.g. "all values passed with exactly the same syntax [curly braces]" vs. "static props without curly braces, all others with is easier to recognize)"

Comment: That's just compile the code and **not checking** the performance. That's actually the final result from the react.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal True, but the snippet demonstrates that the compiler makes no difference between primitive values passed in directly with quotes vs. primitive values surrounded by curly braces.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal There literally can't be a performance difference as far as React is concerned when the two `React.createElement` calls are exactly the same.

Comment: @AKX That's what I am telling. There'll be no performance difference. I'm just telling that the compiler you linked is not for performance check.

Answer (score 4):

> No. It doesn't. React performance is very fast.

Using curly brace, you're telling to React to try to evaluate it and find a string. You're just taking a step longer.

At the end, result will be the same.

Though, I would recommend you to use without the curly brace if it is just a string and not a variable.